# Global time cost versus sum of local time costs -- "for" loop

Tags: c++, performance, time

As silly as it seems, I would like to know whether there may be pitfalls when trying to reconcile the time costs for a `for` loop, as measured

- either from time points just outside the `for` loop (*global* or *external* time cost)
- or, from time points being inside the loop, and being cumulatively considered (*local* or *internal* time cost) ?

The example below illustrates my difficulties getting two equal measurements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> // std::vector
#include <ctime> // clock(), ..

int main(){
  clock_t clockStartLoop;
  double timeInternal(0)// the time cost of the loop, summing all time costs of commands within the "for" loop
    , timeExternal // time cost of the loop, as measured outside the boundaries of "for" loop
    ;
  std::vector<int> vecInt; // will be [0,1,..,10000] after the loop below
  clock_t costExternal(clock());
  for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    clockStartLoop = clock();
    vecInt.push_back(i);
    timeInternal += clock() - clockStartLoop; // incrementing internal time cost
  }
  timeInternal /= CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  timeExternal = (clock() - costExternal)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  std::cout << "timeExternal = "<< timeExternal << " s ";
  std::cout << "vs timeInternal = " << timeInternal << std::endl;
  std::cout << "We have a ratio of " << timeExternal/timeInternal << " between the two.." << std::endl;
}
```

I usually get a ratio around 2 as output e.g.

> timeExternal = 0.008407 s vs timeInternal = 0.004287
>   We have a ratio of 1.96105 between the two..

, whereas I was hoping a ratio closer to 1.

- Is it just because there are operations *internal* to the loop which are not measured by the clock() difference (such as incrementing `timeInternal`) ?
- Could the `i++` operation in the `for(..)` be non-negligible in the external measurement and also explain the difference with the internal one ?

I'm actually dealing with a more complex code and I would like to isolate time costs within a loop, being sure that all the time slices I consider do make up a complete pie (which I never achieved until now..). Thanks a lot

Comment: Most likely most of the time spent is in `clock()` calls themselves, and then you are measuring the cumulative time of 1 clock() call vs 2. Why don't use a proper C++ profiler?

Comment: Because I have no experience (yet ?) in proper profiler.. Maybe it's time to gain some, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you compare two versions of this code: one with only the external time and one with only the sum of the internal times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> timeExternal = 0.008407 s vs timeInternal = 0.004287 We have a ratio of 1.96105 between the two..

A ratio of ~2 is to be expected - by far the heaviest call in your loop is `clock()` itself (on most systems `clock()` is a syscall to the kernel).

Imagine that `clock()` implementation looks like the following *pseudocode*:

```
clock_t clock() {
    go_to_kernel(); // very long operation
    clock_t rc = query_process_clock();
    return_from_kernel(); // very long operation
    return rc;
}
```

Now going back to the loop, we can annotate the places where time is spent:

```
  for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    // go_to_kernel - very long operation
    clockStartLoop = clock();
    // return_from_kernel - very long operation
    vecInt.push_back(i);
    // go_to_kernel - very long operation
    timeInternal += clock() - clockStartLoop;
    // return_from_kernel - very long operation
  }
```

So between the two calls to `clock()` we have 2 long operations, with a total in the loop of 4. Hence the ratio of 2-to-1.

> - Is it just because there are operations internal to the loop which are not measured by the `clock()` difference (such as incrementing `timeInternal`) ?

No, incrementing `timeInterval` is negligible.

> - Could the `i++` operation in the `for(..)` be non-negligible in the external measurement and also explain the difference with the internal one ?

No, `i++` is also negligible. Remove the inner calls to `clock()` and you will see a much faster execution time. On my system it was 0.00003 s.

The next most expensive operation after `clock()` is `vector::push_back()`, because it needs to resize the `vector`. This is amortized by a quadratic growth factor and can be eliminated entirely by calling `vector::reserve()` before entering the loop.

Conclusion: when benchmarking, make sure to time entire loops, not individual iterations. Better yet, use frameworks like [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark), which will help to avoid many other pitfalls (like compiler optimizations). There's also [quick-bench.com](http://quick-bench.com/) for simple cases (based on Google Benchmark).